# Vim how to set visual mode selection from a function?

Tags: vim

I have the start and end (line/col) pairs for my desired selection.

How to set that as the actual visual selection?

Ex:

I have the buffer:

```
 1 2
 3 4
 5 6
```

Start: 2,1

End:   3,2

```
:cal SetSelection()
```

Desired visual selection after call:

```
3 4
5 6
```

What does 'SetSelection()' look like?

EDIT

best solution so far with error checking based on answers

```
"put user in visual mode and set the visual selection

"if arguments are not valid, nothing is changed, and raises an exception

":param 1:

    "Visual mode to leave user in.

    "must be either one of:

    "- 'v' for visual (default)
    "- "\<s-v>" for line visual
    "- "\<c-v>" for block visual
":type 1: string

":returns: 0

":raises: bad mode argument, bad position argument
fu! SetSelection( x, y, x2, y2, ... )
    let valid_mode_strings = ["v","\<s-v>","\<c-v>"]

    if a:0 > 0
        if index( valid_mode_strings, a:1 ) >= 0
            let mode = a:1
        el
            th 'bad mode argument: ' . a:1 . ' valid options: ' . join( valid_mode_strings, ', ' )
        en
    el
        let mode = 'v'
    en

    let oldpos = getpos('.')

    if setpos( '.', [0,a:x,a:y] ) != 0
        exe "norm! \<esc>"
        th 'bad position argument: ' . a:x . ' ' . a:y . ' ' . a:x2 . ' ' . a:y2
    en

    exe 'norm! ' . mode

    if setpos( '.', [0,a:x2,a:y2] ) != 0
        exe "norm! \<esc>"
        cal setpos( '.', oldpos )
        th 'bad position argument: ' . a:x . ' ' . a:y . ' ' . a:x2 . ' ' . a:y2
    en
endf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use function `setpos()` to do the job:

```
fun! SetSelection()
    call setpos('.',[0,2,1])
    normal! v
    call setpos('.',[0,3,2])
endf
```

in above codes, the `[2,1]` and `[3,2]` should be as arguments passed in. I just hard coded to make it simple.

also some error handling was left to you. e.g. argument validation etc.

Comment: thanks a lot, this works. I just don't understand why the following does not work: 1) start on visual mode 2) type `:` to go to command mode 3) erase the `'<,'>` 4) type `setpos( '.', [0,3,2] )` and enter. If I do this I simply leave visual mode and start at normal mode on position `[0,3,2]`

Answer (score 3):

Most vim have a `m<` and `m>` markers for exactly this purpose. `:help m<`

```
call setpos("'<", [0, 2, 1])
call setpos("'>", [0, 3, 2])
normal! gv
```

Some vim installation don't. In those cases, you can save and restore a user mark, or use the context mark `` ` ``

```
call cursor([2, 1])
normal! m`
call cursor([3, 2])
normal! v``
```